# How to use MSBUild 2010 to write scripts

Tags: msbuild

I am working on MSBuild 2010 and TFS 2010. Heard that one can also use MSBuild apart from using Windows Workflow. My question is how? How do i create a MSBuild project and see the .proj file just like i used to in TFS 2008/ MSBuild 2008

Answer (score 0):

If you have builds that you've created in TFS 2008 that you want to use now, create a build definition that uses the UpgradeTemplate.xaml. This template was created for porting over earlier TFS builds and lets you specify the TfsBuild.proj file that was used in TFS 2008.

Other than that, if you are just looking to use MSBuild scripts instead of the workflow in your build process, you can do that as well (though it is more difficult now.) In VS 2010, you can specify what you want to build when creating a build definition - it defaults to solutions in source control but it can be any msbuild script. Just select an msbuild script that you've created and go from there. For this route, I would recommend the DefaultTemplate.xaml, which you will definitely need to modify along the way.